# error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: libraries, shared-library

I'm getting this error when I execute my db_server

```
**root@v-8966:/home/talisman/db# ./db_server

./db_server: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

`libmysqlclient.so.15` is no longer available in any supported version of Ubuntu. Ask your program's developers if a more recent version, linked against a more recent version of libmysqlclient, exists. If not, you might be out of luck.

Comment: I'm trying this on a vps and in my virtual machine this works

Comment: It probably installs an alias of some sort then... You probably have some version of `libmysqlclient` installed on your virtual machine, just install that same version on your VPS.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't install the MySQL client for PHP.
Try installing it

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

I am assuming that you are using the default PHP 5 that comes with Ubuntu.

Comment: It says its already installed in the newest version

Comment: Do you have more than 1 php installed? Can you check that out?

Comment: Oh, my bad, after reading fkraiem's answer found out is not about PHP mysql client library. You should check the version of your OSes on your virtual machine and on the vps. The differences will give you some idea.